# Technical Profile fails to match user account with email (signInNames.emailAddress) claim

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Can anyone explain to me (before Azure B2C Custom Policies make me pull what's left of my hair out), why this technical profile fails to ever return an "objectId" when a user account exists in Azure B2C.  I am collecting the email claim in a previous screen and calling the technical profile from the orchestration step.

I can see the profile executing in my Application Insights logs and I have confirmed that the email address I use in the claim is in the directory.  But every time, no matter which email address I use, I never get an objectId back which means I can never detect if the user exists or not!

**Technical Profile**

```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="UE-AAD-CheckAccountExistsByEmail">
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
        Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided email address.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

**Orchestration Step**

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <!-- Skip this if we already have an object id from single signon -->
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectIdFromSession</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <!-- Call a technical profile to see if an account can be found with the email supplied in AD -->
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AccountExistsClaim"
          TechnicalProfileReferenceId="UE-AAD-CheckAccountExistsByEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified `ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider` as the handler.
You need the AAD provider as the handler to make Graph API queries.
Though if AAD-Common already has the Protocol element, you don't need to specify it here again since it'll be included from there.

Like so:

```xml
     <TechnicalProfile Id="UE-AAD-CheckAccountExistsByEmail">
        <!-- You don't actually need this though if AAD-Common has it -->
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureActiveDirectoryProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided email address.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider is used for running claims transformations to produce new claims or modify existing claims.
It is not used for querying AAD.